# array.reduce with incorrect results

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given:

```js
let rows = [
    { Amount: 190615.83 },
    { Amount: -175867.95 },
    { Amount: -14747.88 },
]
const sum = rows.reduce((runSum, v) => runSum + v.Amount, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

The sum should return 0 but it returns `-2.3646862246096134e-11`
see: https://jsfiddle.net/Brobic/q78nypuc/1/
How can I make this add correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 1):

The behavior  you see has nothing to do with `array.reduce()`. If you add those numbers individually, you will see similar output. This is how floating point `numbers` behave in most programming languages.

See code snippet below. General expectation is that both these log console logs `0.0`:

```js
console.log(190615.83 - 175867.95 - 14747.88);
console.log(1.1 + 2.2 - 3.3);
```

Also see more details in the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/11057988).

Answer (score 0):

Thats how floating point  numbers behave , you can fix it , if you know the precision, in this case it was `2`:

```js
let rows = [
    { Amount: 190615.83 },
    { Amount: -175867.95 },
    { Amount: -14747.88 },
]

const sum =  rows.map(a=>parseFloat(a.Amount)).reduce((runSum, v) => (parseFloat(runSum) + parseFloat(v)).toFixed(2));
console.log(sum);
```

This produces output `0.00`

The `parseFloat` is meant for keeping dataType as float , so that the method `toFixed()` can be applied